# Keep section heading with following float

Tags: floats, sectioning, samepage

I am writing a book in LaTeX from Python.

In each chapter there exists a section *Documents*; the section contains scans of documents, which are included as `\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{"/filePath/DocumentScan.png"}`.
I am preventing the figure from floating across sections using `\FloatBarrier` from package `placins`.

I do however have the situation that the section heading is on one page, and by lack of space on that page, the figure is positioned on the next page. This leaves a large gap of white between the section heading and the figure - see attached screenshot.

In such cases I would prefer to have the section heading *also* move to the next page, and stay with the (floating) figure.

As the document is quite long, is there a way to solve this in LaTeX without manually having to add `\newpages`?

[image]

--- EDIT 1

A minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[hidelinks,a4paper,titlepage,10pt]{book}%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}%
\usepackage[section]{placeins}%
\usepackage{blindtext}%
\usepackage{tikz}
%
\makeatletter%
%
\begin{document}%
\normalsize%
\chapter{Chapter 1}%
\section{Section 1}%
\blindtext
    
\section{Section 2}
\begin{figure}[h]%
\centering%
\begin{tikzpicture}
            
\node[rectangle,draw, minimum width = \textwidth, minimum height = \textwidth] (r) at (0,0) {Figure};
        
\end{tikzpicture}

\caption{Figure Caption}%
\end{figure}%

\FloatBarrier
\end{document}
```

Comment: Well, that happens when you prevent the figure from floating. I'd suggest using a float with `[htbp]` options, and experimenting with the float code placement within the LaTeX code. Also, if you have multiple documents to include, try a small one first (to fill the white gap) or experiment with the document height.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE :) // I suggest to include some code excerpt, which shows your problem. It should contain the preamble, so we can copy, paste and compile it right away. Thanks

Comment: @Hans I think you may have accidentally created two accounts, one to ask the question and one to add a MWE. If this is the case you can ask a moderator for help merging them

Answer (score 0):

Solved - but maybe not the nicest solution

1. Making the figure non-floating *and* making use of the `caption`-package keeps the section heading together with the figure following it.
2. Putting the Chapter heading + complete first section in a minipage to remove additional whitespacing between headings on the first page

See screenshot below.

Code:

```
\documentclass[hidelinks,a4paper,titlepage,10pt]{book}%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}%
\usepackage[section]{placeins}%
\usepackage{blindtext}%
\usepackage{tikz}
%
\makeatletter%
%
\begin{document}%
    \normalsize%
    \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    \chapter{Chapter 1}%
    \section{Section 1}%
    \blindtext
    \end{minipage}
    
    \section{Section 2}
%   \begin{figure}[htbp]%
    \centering%
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            
            \node[rectangle,draw, minimum width = \textwidth,   minimum height = \textwidth] (r) at (0,0) {Figure};
            
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \captionof{figure}{Caption}%
%   \end{figure}%
    \FloatBarrier
\end{document}
```

[image]